# Uniform convergence on compact sets when derivatives go to zero

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions in $\mathbb{D}$. I want to prove that if:

1. For some $M>0$, $|f_n(z)|\leq M$ for every $z\in \mathbb{D}$ and every $n\geq1$.
2. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^{(k)}_n(z)=0$ for all $k\geq 0$

then $f_n$ converges uniformly on compact sets to $0$. What I have to show is that for every $R\in (0,1)$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{z\in \overline{\mathbb{D}(0,R)}}|f_n(z)|=0$$
I don't know how to use the info that I have on the derivatives in this expression. Can someone help me?

Comment: is $2$ given for a specific $z$ or for all $z$ (by Montel if $|f_n| \le M$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then $f$ is holomorphic and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compacts,)

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, the convergence of functions is always supposed to be uniform on compact sets.

By Montel's theore, $\{f_n\}$ is a normal family so there's a subsequence such that $f_{n_k}\to f$. Cauchy's formula now implies that $f_{n_k}^{(m)}\to f^{(m)}$,  so $f^{(k)}(z_0)=0$ for every $k\ge 0$, which implies $f\equiv 0$.
The same reasoning proves that every subsequence of $f_n$ has a subsequence converging to $0$ and this proves by a standard argument in metric topology that $f_n\to 0$.

Comment: What is the "standard argument in metric topology"?

Comment: @kubo In a compact metric space, a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ if for every subsequence $x_{n_k}$ we have $x\in\overline{\{x_{n_k}\}}$. This statement is easy to prove:  suppose that $x_n\not \to x$.  Then there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $d(x_{n_k},x)>\varepsilon>0$ and this contradicts the fact that $x$ must be in the closure of $\{x_{n_k}\}$.